# Wordpress mobile menu bug: sub-menu auto closing after opening

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu, themes, expand

The problem:

The sub-menu of my wordpress website [polywolves.com](https://polywolves.com/en/) closes automatically after clicking on the + icon to open it. So it expands all items underneath and then the items disappear again.

What I did:

When I open the console in Google I can see that it changes from display:none to display:block and then I goes back to display:none. 
I have tried completely reinstalling my wordpress theme (north) and turning off all plugins. I also tried activating the wordpress theme rather then it's child theme so no css could cause the problem.

What I would like:

I would like to know what is causing this problem so I can fix it, or get help with some code that fixes this problem.

Question:

How can I prevent my mobile menu from toggling back to display:none after clicking on the + button to expand it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow >this is not the right place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: May I ask what would be the right place to ask?

Comment: @PolyWolves Please rework your "question" to state and actual goal / question. Also include a link to the page in question &/or all the relevant code. Then it will be appropriate for this forum and we can get to work trying to help you. You should also point out what you have done to try and fix the issue. If however this is a question not related to you doing some coding, you should go to [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you, I changed the question. Of course I am willing to do some coding!